# How to copy members between classes in intellij

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, structure, move, members

I recently changed from eclipse to intellij idea, and, from time to time, I found things that are missing in the, otherwise quite good, new IDE that were present in my beloved Eclipse.

One thing that I miss the most is the Overview view in Eclipse, since the Structure view in Intellij doesn't allow to move things around, or follow the members in the same order that are defined in the source file (the structure view put always the methods before the fields), etc.

Recently, I needed to copy some fields and their getter's and setter's, from one Class to another. In Eclipse, you could copy them directly in the overview view and paste it in the overview of another class and it would came with everything (annotations, javadoc, imports, etc.). Do you know if there is any way of doing something similar in Intellij, apart from copying it by hand, that makes you be very careful, so you don't forget anything in the process.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like this other question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109137/copying-class-members-into-other-classes-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, while I was writing the question, I come up with a suitable solution, though is a workaround and not straight-forward as I would expect.

I was just thinking that the "pull up..." re-factoring does something similar to what I was looking for, but in a hierarchy of classes, which was not the case, so, how could make the classes be in the same hierarchy without messing with the real hierarchy of the classes? Creating a copy of the class where I wanted to copy the fields from.

Then, I just needed to make that class extends from the the one that I wanted to copy to fields to, call to the "pull up..." re-factoring and select what I want to copy.

**Tip here**: If you first select the getter's and setter's, intellij will change automatically the color of the font of the fields, making them easier to select.